# Out of Memory error in Shiny Apps but the files don't exceed 1 GB?

Tags: r, debugging, shinyapps

I'm trying to deploy my app to Shiny Apps from R, but every time I try to do so, it gives me an out of memory error. I tried to create a feature where instead of uploading files directly from the user's computer, they were able to choose files from an in built dropdown. I cleared my memory on my app and it's still giving me and OOM error. I checked all the files in my app, and they total to 20 KB, which is way less than 1 GB.

However, when I'm trying to deploy, I notice something different than the previous ones I've tried to deploy. It gives me a part where it says "Uploading Bundle", and then it uploads every file in my Documents directory.

However, that still does not exceed 1 GB. How do I fix the OOM error?

Memory Usage:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/12WpgkHeuUlWFEjQDgGaoH-nsoV9MkVZnIQPasbjIE4g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's unlikely that it (directly) related to bundle size, files and storage, something in your running Shiny app causes memory (RAM) usage to peak. What's happening under the hood? Where does it load data from, and what kind of data? Any long loops in the code? Nested loops? Recursions? How much memory does it use when you run it locally?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! How do I check how much memory it uses when I run it locally? As for loading data, it loads from my documents in file explorer (in jpg form). There are no long loops or nested loops in my code. I have updated my original post with memory usage info.

Comment: You can see current memory usage in Environment tab of RStudio.  Same widged opens Memory usage report.It's not the most accurate method, but if you keep your eye on it when launching your Shiny app, you should get an idea if it peaks somewhere to somewhere close to 1GB.